# Meaning of XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is)?

Tags: java, apache-poi

What exactly it means when I call the constructor XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream is). I am new to java, and I am looking for an answer in layman terms.

Comment: What is unclear in API javadoc for this constructor? https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook(java.io.InputStream)

Can you elaborate what part you don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are talking about the Apache POI API XSSFWorkbook. In this case, when you are calling the constructor, you are specifying the inputstream of an excel file.

for example

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\...\\MyExcelFile.xlsx");
```

That would be initializing a new InputStream, where you could pass that into the XSSFWorkbook

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
```

Then you could make changes/get information by using the various methods of the XSSFWorkbook class.